# Difference between 試験{しけん} and テスト

Tags: word-choice, usage

Both can be test, or they have a different meaning/usage?

"試験{しけん}を受ける{うける}."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both basically share the same meaning, and are interchangeable in most cases. For example, there is no difference between 期末試験 and 期末テスト.

But there are set phrases where only one of them is used.

- 入学試験 entrance exam ((*)入学テスト is unusual)
- テスト駆動開発 [test-driven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) ((*)試験駆動開発 is unusual)

And I think 試験 sounds a bit more formal and serious. Critical tests/exams tend to be called 試験, whereas casual tests or tests you do every day tend to be called テスト.

Comment: I think it'd make sense to say that 「テスト」 is probably more common than 「試験」 when it comes to computing-related concepts. 「単体テスト」、「回帰テスト」、「ストレステスト」 seem better than the 〜試験 versions to me, though I think they all work (unlike 「試験駆動開発」).